# asp.net MVC partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, partial

I have created a function for load event like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#dvGames').load(
     '<%= Url.Action("Partial3", "LiveGame") %>',{ gameDate: '2011-03-06' }
  );
});
```

and it works. Also, I have created a function for date change like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: "/LiveGame/Partial3",             

            data: "gameDate=" + dateText,

            success: function(result) {

                alert(result);

                var domElement = $(result); // create element from html

                $("#dvGames").append(domElement); // append to end of list        

            }

        });

    }

  });
});
```

but it doesnt work. neither it goes in controller action. My controller action is:

```
 public ActionResult Partial3(string gameDate)
    {

        return PartialView("Partial3");

    }
```

Please suggest me solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options will work for this

```
url: "/LiveGame/Partial3?gameDate=" + dateText
```

or

```
data: { gameDate : dateText }
```

don't use both and the 2nd is probably best practice use of JSON.

I don't like query strings in MVC post callbacks as they will persist across posts even if you don't want them to.

Comment: Hi Gats: I tried url: "/LiveGame/Partial3?gameDate=" + dateText and removed data: { gameDate : dateText }
 but still it is not going in controller action on dateselection change.

Comment: Then you might have a problem with your onselect. It's a jquery issue as well then. Is the datepicker set up correctly? There can also be problems with your routing in MVC, Try going to the controller url (/LiveGame/Partial3?gameDate=mydate")directly and seeing if you get a 404 or not.

Comment: @Gates: I tried  http://localhost:2892/LiveGame/Partial3?gameDate=mydate and it showed me partial view.

Comment: puta alert on second function and check whether it's called.

Comment: @Jayantha: I tried this :    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            alert('Testing');
            $.ajax({   and it is not showing alert.

Comment: Then it's definitely something wrong with the datepicker setup. Your jquery event isn't firing properly.

Comment: @Gats. thanks you are right. I am calling datepicker two times. my mistake. I remove first one and it worked.